# Rails 5: Database design with iterations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, relational-database

I currently have a site with Users, Meals, and Orders tables.

- Users table holds the User information
- Meals table holds the Meal name, description, img(url)

I am currently displaying the Meals using an iteration:

```
<% @meals.each do |meal| %>
 <%= image_tag(meal.img,  alt: meal.name) %>
 <span class="mealname"><%= meal.name %></span>
 <p><%= meal.description %><p>

   <div class="qty">
       INPUT FOR ORDER QTYS HERE
   </div>

<% end %>
```

- Orders table holds the qty's that the user wants for each Meal

Orders migration for reference:

```
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.integer :total_meals, null: false, default:"0"
  t.integer :meal1, null: false, default: "0"
  t.integer :meal2, null: false, default: "0"
  etc..
```

Before I was not using an iteration and had the respective meal1, meal2, etc matching up to the Meals in the HTML layout.

This obviously can be done better, however considering I need the Meals information to be able to be updated dynamically (I want to use the iteration above), How should I go about dealing with this?

But also... if I use another table, how would I possibly be able to implement that into the iteration and populate correctly?

I could add a 'qty' column to the Meals table and make it belong_to :user, but that is also obviously bad practice and will get really messy really quick.

Comment: In orders table you only want the total number of meals or you also want the info of the meals

Comment: The info for the meals is global, every user will see the same meals. The user can only change their qty for each meal (this is the current purpose of the orders table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the information something like:

> Order has meal 1, meal 2 and meal 3 and order belongs to User 1

Then you should have the right associations among these 3 models. `User`, `Meal` and `Order`

One `Order` can have many meals, and one `Meal` can belong to many orders, So `Order` and `Meal` will have `many-to-many association`.

And an `Order` will `belong to` a `User`

**Solution:**

Change your `Order` model to:

```
t.belongs_to :user
```

Add a fourth model, you can name it `Quantity`:

```
t.belongs_to :order
t.belongs_to :meal
t.integer :quantity
```

Now let's say User A, selects 2 units of Meal A, 3 units of Meal B, you will create an order A, for this user, and Order A will have two entries in `Quantity` model containing the info of meal id and their respective quantities.

**Update:**
Models will look like this:

Order.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :quantities
has_many :meals, through: :quantities
```

Quantity.rb

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :meal
```

Meal.rb

```
has_many :quantities
has_many :orders, through: :quantities
```

User.rb

```
has_many :orders
```

Then, if you want to get the total number of orders one meal has get, you can get it by:

```
meal.orders.count
```

and if you want to get all the meals one order has and their quantities:

```
order.quantities.each do |record|
  record.meal.name # for name of associated meal
  record.quantity # for quantity of meal
end
```

Comment: The Many to Many relationship makes way more sense now. So then as for displaying the Meal info and the Quantity in the same iteration, would I just bring in that quantity field somehow and leave the iteration as is?

Comment: with a quick reference to the rails guide and your help, I now fully understand the use of :through, which I now realize is vital in these types of relationships. I was not thinking this was even possible before. Thank you.