# Rails 5: Many-to-Many relationships and Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, relational-database

Per a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023671/rails-5-displaying-form-from-joined-table) , I understand how to set up my tables/Models so that I can setup a Many-to-Many relationship

However, what I am trying to do is to implement all of this on 1 page with 1 form. (The only other page the user will see is a confirmation page after they have submitted the form, possibly just displaying the details of what they submitted)

The User only needs to be able to update the quantities of any of the available Meals. I will then make a backup of the database on a certain day/time and that will be every User's order for the week. Because of this, I have restructured my tables as follows...

**User** stores the user's information.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mealselections
  has_many :meals, through: :mealselections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mealselections
end
```

**Meal** is used to display the information of the meals to all users. (meal_name, description, img_url)

meal.rb

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mealselections
  has_many :users, through: :mealselections
end
```

**MealSelection** is the joined table that references the Meals the User chose, and then an additional integer column is added to this table that denotes the qty of meals they want for each meal selection

mealselection.rb

```
class MealSelection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :meals
end
```

So where I am lost is how to utilize the controller to be able to perform CRUD functionality from a single form. This made more sense when I had a 1-to-1 relationship as I was just updating the columns (meal1, meal2, meal3) for the related user and each meal# column was created with a default value of 0.

However now because of how Many-to-Many relationships work, I realize that the user at minimum has to create and update columns from the same form.

Since I am showing this on one page (homepage), how do I make this happen in the respective HomeController with one form/request?

Comment: It sounds to me like the thing you actually want the user to do on the page is to add/remove MealSelections for an order.  It is very difficult to model a many-to-many relationship to the user on a flat page.  Personally, I would sketch out what the page will look like/what buttons the user has and use that to plan out what you are doing.  Truly modelling the many-to-many relationship on a single page will prove rather difficult but a page for editing the MealSelections of a single Order should prove fairly straightforward.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I should be really just focusing on the MealSelections as that is really the only thing that is actively changing. Also good to know that modeling Many-to-Many on a single page is not something that is easily accomplished. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Though a little dated, the content in http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised demonstrates a common technique which involves modifying the form as the user is making selections to create, remove, or modify the fields of the nested model(s) using javascript. This basic principle is still commonly used, as it leans on the default nested attribute logic in the controller and model mass-update mechanisms. There are some minor tweaks you may have to make with strong parameters being a factor on more modern apps than was common at the time the content was produced. A look at the code for the form  and controller action(s) in question might help with a more specific answer as well.

Comment: I am going to attempt to utilize the simplified setup as stated in the comment to my question, but this info is great if I feel I need to expand functionality down the road. Thank you.